# RadioGroup doesn't work over different activities

Tags: android

I've been trying to set up a three-button RadioGroup that is permanently visible/usable in two activities (Activity1 and Activity2). Activity2 extends Activity1 so that all working variables (strings and integers) only need to be defined in Activity1.

I put the RadioGroup in a dedicated layout-xml, which is then incorporated (using "include") in the layout-xml of each activity. The method checkButton(), to be executed upon a radio button selection [android:onClick="checkButton()] is defined in the java code of Activity1. The execution of checkButton() changes the values of the variables displayed in the TextViews of both Activity1 and Activity2.

The set-up works as intended for Activity1. But in Activity2, it works only cosmetically; when I check one of the buttons, this doesn't seem to execute checkButton().

I've tried copying the code of checkButton() into Activity2, adding to its body the TextView.setText() "update" lines for Activity2. This had no either effect.

If no immediate solution for this set-up is at hand, is there perhaps an alternative set-up?

Comment: Could you please paste some or the code?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think extending an activity from another activity a good idea.because activities are initialized at runtime by android framework.each of them will have their own lifecycle.However please share your code for more clarity..